# How big of a portal does one need to allow Ghasts to enter the Overworld?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

According to the [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ghast_Fireball#History) in 1.7.2 a Ghast could enter the overworld

> 1.7.2 - Ghasts can now enter the Overworld in survival with bigger Nether portals.

just how big does a Nether Portal need to be to allow Ghasts to enter the Overworld?

Answer (score 5):

5x5 should do the trick, at minimum.

[image: Squeezing a Ghast in should work.. maybe.]

If you can somehow manage to squeeze a Ghast into the portal the resualting effect shall send the Ghast to the Overworld.  Even if the portal on the Overworld is smaller.
 [image: Oh dear..]

*Spawn eggs were only used in the nether.*

Comment: Do note that the ghast may suffocate when comming out of a smaller overworld portal